# Performing operations after reading the last line of a file with a StreamReader

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, streamreader

I am using a `StreamReader` to read lines from a text file. For each line I have specific operations that are performed.

Example:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileDirectory); //Open StreamReader
while ((inFileString = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if(something)
    { do stuff... }
}
```

My problem occurs after the last line is read, because the code inside the `while` loop becomes inaccessible. It's basically like I need to be allowed to go through the `while` loop one more time, after it automatically exits. How do I perform my operations on the last line read from the file?

(I could just replicate the operations outside of the loop, but I figured that would be inefficient...)

Comment: Out of curiousity why not just use `File.ReadAllLines(fileDirectory)` instead of opening a stream and then reading the lines? That'll give you an array you can iterate over.

Comment: @siva.k when file is big, reading all text inside memory could not be a good thig. I think that OP approach is good since his business logic allows to process file line-by-line.

Comment: @pwas Ah, yeah, good point.

Comment: @pwas In that case I suggest `File.ReadLines` which is lazy and a better alternate.

Comment: I'm guessing you've already done this, but it doesn't hurt to ask. Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger to make sure that you're skipping the `while` loop on the last line of the file?

Comment: @IchabodClay I have tried that. I stepped through it, and after reading the last line, it doesn't go through the while loop again -- which is how a while loop behaves. Right now I'm debugging and trying some of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this looks acceptable.

```
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"D:\Downloads\testfile.txt"))
{
    string str = "";
    while ((str = file.ReadLine()) != null || str == null)
    {
        if (str == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hey! We've already passed the EOF!");
            break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I ended up changing my answer to this due to simplicity. @CalvinSmith's answer worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe note the best solution but...

```
int TotalLines(string filePath)
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (r.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            i++;
        }

        return i;
    }
}

//Open StreamReader
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileDirectory);

for (int q = 0; q <= TotalLines + 1; i++)
{
    file.ReadLine();

    if (q == int + 1)
    { 
        //do stuff...
    }
}
```

Its not the cleanest code, but I've never been perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Peek()` method?

```
using (var strReader = new System.IO.StreamReader())
{
    while (strReader.Peek() > -1)
    {
        var line = strReader.ReadLine();

        // Do Something
    }
    strReader.Close();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it seems to work exactly the same, with my problem being that the operations on the last line are ignored.